# Html minifier in client side

Tags: javascript, client-side, html-minifier

How can I minify an html string on client side with html minifier ?

I already take a look to [html-minifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-minifier) it work well on node.js but i don't know if it's possible to use it in browser environnement.

Anyone can provide a working example ?

Comment: Can you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36606082/clientside-html-minification


You can have a function on the client side that takes the html string and uses `String.replace(/\n[ ]*/g,"")` to do the minification.


Not the best solution, but client-side minification isn't really ideal to begin with.

Comment: Yep i already see. But in fact my goal is to use html minifier in front end part. I can not do it in backend because I generate html in frontend part. My project is a webapp who generate html template dynamically with form value.

Comment: You could modify a version of `html-minifier` to have it attach the global `window` and expose it, then host it on a CDN that you can just refer to on the client side. Though that's too much. Have you tried [Browserify](http://browserify.org/)?

Comment: Finaly find a solution, here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/html-minifier-in-browser-client-side-html-minification-tj7i0