# How to use html-minifier module in browser?

Tags: javascript, node-modules, browserify

I just want to use function from **html-minifier** in the browser.

I have tried using [Browserify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49562978/how-to-use-npm-modules-in-browser-is-possible-to-use-them-even-in-local-pc) to make bundle using these commands:
`browserify -r html-minifier -o html-minifier.js`
`browserify -r html-minifier -s htmlMinifier -o html-minifier.js`

Also tried importing as module and script but it gives **`require.resolve is not a function`**

Even tried CDNs like [Skypack](https://cdn.skypack.dev/html-minifier)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65343130/html-minifier-in-client-side) issue provides a pre-built minified bundle which works but I need to create the bundle myself for latest version after some changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier/blob/gh-pages/Gruntfile.js is the Gruntfile used to generate the solution you point to. The Gruntfile uses browserify but with a lot of specific settings. Given that html-minifier hasn't seen a new version published in 4 years and the Gruntfile is about 4 years old, it seems likely that it will work to build the browser-based html-minifier for you.